# Modifying R object in C++

Tags: c++, r

I am concerned with the following question:
How likely is changing vectors in C++, that were allocated in R, to cause problems?

I know that r-developers recommend read-only access to R-objects
and if one wants to modify, we have to copy stuff.
And this is exactly what I am trying to avoid in a very limited application
frame, which is this:

Before I call my C++ function I already know that I want to return a vector
of doubles and I know how long it is supposed to be.
I dont want to deal with external pointers, which do not seem to offer a convenient
solution for what I am trying to accomplish.
So I take this approach:
I preallocate the vector I need before calling the C++-function. I pass this 
vector as argument to the function, I grep the pointer to the array and modify elements
of that array directly in C++. So I dont return anything.

So here is my example C++ function (using inline and RcppEigen):

```
code <- 

'

int n = *INTEGER(nR);
int p = *INTEGER(pR);

double * xin = REAL(XR);
double * yin = REAL(yR);
double * solin = REAL(solR);

Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> X(xin,n,p);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> y(yin,p,n);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> sol(solin,n,n);

sol.noalias() = X*y;

'

settings <- getPlugin("RcppEigen")
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS <- paste('-fopenmp -O2 ', settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS)
settings$env$PKG_LIBS <- paste('-fopenmp -lgomp', settings$env$PKG_LIBS)

fun <- cxxfunction(signature(XR="numeric", yR="numeric", solR="numeric",nR="intger",pR="integer"), code, plugin="RcppEigen",settings=settings)
```

Now in R I would do this:

```
n = as.integer(100)
p = as.integer(3000)

X<-matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p)

# preallocating the solution vector
sol = double(n*n)

# calling the c++ functions while passing the solution vector  
fun(X,t(X),sol,n,p)

# check if we get same results:

dim(sol) <- c(n,n)
all.equal(tcrossprod(X),sol)
```

That way I avoided an unnecessary copy of the solution vector.
I played around with that a bit and I did not encounter problems,
but appearently there have to be some as this approach is absolutely not
recommended.
So what are the traps I am running into ?

Comment: Can you expand on what you think is recommend, and what is not, and maybe provide a reference?  There are 24 CRAN packages using RcppEigen you could look at in detail too (as well as 87 more for RcppArmadillo).  There is no mystique to the memory management, and Rcpp and friends help you automate it.  Without loss of performance or extra copies.

Comment: Also, as it stands, this sentence is false: _"I know that r-developers recommend read-only access to R-objects and if one wants to modify, we have to copy stuff."_

Comment: my question was not specifically aimed at Rcpp/RcppEigen, maybe I should have used an example without Eigen. I dont have a quote from an r-developer, so that was just my guess. One reference I could give is the discussion from here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2010-October/058923.html

Comment: You may want to memory-profile something like `Rcppp::cppFunction("Rcpp::NumericVector myvecfun(Rcpp::NumericVector X, double k) { return X*k; } ")` -- there should be no copy.  You can achieve the same in plain C, it just takes more characters on your end if you don't use what Rcpp has for you there.

Comment: thanks, I see now how I can accomplish the same behaviour directly in C++ with an Rcpp::NumericMatrix. From this the answer to my initial question would be: There is nothing dangerous about modifying R objects on the C++-side without doing a copy. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Rcpp has been doing it for years.  But do read "Writing R Extensions" about accessing R's allocators -- which is what we do.